# Is it possible to change colour for particular x and y coordinate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw

For e.g. take a look at this :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
     path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 1, 1)];

    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

}
```

**What i tried :**
C

```
GRect topRect = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y, 10,10);
// Fill the rectangle with grey
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
UIRectFill( topRect );
[self.view drawRect:topRect];
```

**But its giving me error :**

> <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

When user moves the touch I get the coordinate and changing the colour.
when user moving their hand x and y coordinates are generating ,for that particular place i like to change colour.

If its possible please give some tips.

Comment: do you want to draw line on fingure moves ?

Comment: @Mayur yep you correct

Comment: please check it: https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View

Comment: When is the draw code executed?

Comment: inside the touch move method @Cristik

Comment: That's the problem, you should call drawing functions only when in the `drawRect:` method of the view. Only then a valid drawing context is available.

Comment: can you explain it brief please @Cristik

Comment: @KishoreKumar I added an answer with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any drawing operation must be done within the [view drawing cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW136). You cannot draw stuff at any point time, you can do this only when the view is being drawn.

This implies overwriting the `drawRect:` method in your UIView subclass, if you don't have one, then you'll need to add it:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    GRect topRect = CGRectMake(self.touchedPoint.x,touchedPoint.y, 10,10);
    // Fill the rectangle with grey
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( topRect );
    [self.view drawRect:topRect];
}
```

The next step is to pass to information from your controller, the one that receives the `touchesMoved:` message, to the view. This can be done via a property on the view:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint touchedPoint;
```

And lastly, after you pass along the point details, you need to tell the view that it needs to redraw, by calling [setNeedsDisplay](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay):

```
((MyViewSubclass*)self.view).touchedPoint = touchPoint;
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: @Christik Where i have to give that drawRect method in uiview subclass or uiview controller ?

Comment: `UIView` - check the link from my anwser.

Comment: bro everythind i done well ,but i dont know how i have to pass the current position to subclass of uiview.

Comment: As I said in the answer, you can add a property to the view, that you set from the controller when receiving the touch.

Comment: @KishoreKumar I added usage example for the property.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cristik answer is quite correct let me just add on how to inject the touch events. The problem in having a touch as a `CGPoint` property is you will not know when no touches are made. Second you will not be able to inject multiple touches.

So rather try with an array in your view. `NSValue` may help you store the point as an object:

```
// assuming you have a property:
// @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *touchesYetToProcess;

- (void)injectTouchAtLocation:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    NSMutableArray *items = self.touchesYetToProcess; // a property holding the touches
    [items addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *items = self.touchesYetToProcess;
    NSArray *newTouches = [items copy]; //= copy the touches
    [items removeAllObjects]; // clear the buffer
    for(NSValue *touchValue in newTouches) {
        CGPoint point = touchValue.CGPointValue;
        // do whatever you want with the point
    }
}
```